# Violin plot in plotly enclosing individual data points

Tags: python, plotly, violin-plot

How can I create a violin plot that encloses individual data points?

The code below displays the violin and the individual data points next to each other; however, rather than next to each other I want the violin to enclose the points (magenta arrow)?

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.violin(df, y="total_bill", box=False, # draw box plot inside the violin
                points='all', # can be 'outliers', or False
               )
fig.show()
```

[image: Violin plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using plotly `graph_objects`. You have to set the `pointpos` attribute which sets the position of the sample points in relation to the violins. If "0", the sample points are places over the center of the violins. (https://plotly.com/python/reference/violin/)

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.tips()

### define the chart
data = go.Violin(y=df['total_bill'], points='all', pointpos=0)

### assign the chart to the figure
fig = go.Figure(data=data)

### show the plot
fig.show()
```

[image]